# Table -> Function dependency via a virtual column not in all_dependencies?

Tags: oracle, dependencies, data-dictionary

I've got the following objects:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CONSTFUNC RETURN INT
DETERMINISTIC
AS
BEGIN
RETURN 1;
END;

CREATE TABLE "FUNCTABLE" (
  "ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL,
  "VIRT" NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS ("CONSTFUNC"()) NULL
);
```

however, the functable => constfunc dependency is not listed in all_ or user_ dependencies. Is there anywhere I can access this dependency information in the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created your function and table in 11G (11.1) and can confirm your findings. I couldn't find anything in the Oracle docs either.

If you drop the function, the table status remains "VALID", but when you select from the table you get ORA-00904: "CHAMP"."CONSTFUNC": invalid identifier.  This suggests that Oracle itself isn't aware of the dependency.

It might be worth asking this question on asktom.oracle.com, because Tom Kyte will have access to more information - he may even raise a bug about it if need be.

Comment: It looks like Oracle just hasn't fully baked this new feature.  I had a thought that perhaps a TABLE couldn't be a referencing object type, but I have databases where tables have columns defined as TYPE(s) and these do show the dependencies correctly

Answer (score 0):

The expression used to generate the virtual column is listed in the DATA_DEFAULT column of the [DBA|ALL|USER]_TAB_COLUMNS views.

Comment: But I want the actual dependency information of the expression, not the expression text. I don't want to parse the text and lookup the object identifiers myself!

Comment: I'm not sure why I get negative points for this. It may not be the answer you are looking for but it is a correct answer to your question.